# Differences between debuggable and not debuggable builds in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This question is related to a problem with my firebase, having the "debuggable true" option, which impact has in my program apart of enable testing?
When I configure another build or just the same but with "debuggable=false" the firebase can't be serialized. Why is this happening? Thanks

I though the proguard could be the solution but I'm using this build and changing debuggable to false is the problem.

**Update**

With proguard enabled or not, the result is the same with these permissions (I dont want any change in my code):

```
-dontwarn com.firebase.**
-dontoptimize
-keep class acr.acr_app.** { *; }
-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
```

**Gradle.Build**

```
        release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        debuggable true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

**Udpate 2**

I updated the libraries with no effect, somebody can help me a bit? How run app compile the app?

Comment: Are you saying that you build your app with "debuggable=true" and it works, then you rebuild with "debuggable=false" and NO other changes, and you get failures related to serializing database objects?

Comment: can you pls explain in detail, what you mean?

Comment: Most likely the Proguard settings are different between a debuggable build and a release build. You'll need to modify the Proguard rules for your program. Didn't you ask the same question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118517/when-my-app-its-not-debuggable-my-firebase-doesnt-work (most of these answers will be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D+proguard)

Comment: Well I found some answer about disabling proguard, but mine is set up to false, why should be enabled? Sorry

Comment: Yes I only only change  "debuggable=true" to false and doesnt work.